# Calculating the length of a helix

Tags: calculus

I have a pipe and I want to put a wire through it in a helix form. I need to calculate how long the wire (wl) has to be. I know the internal diameter (id), and therefore the circumference (c). I know the length of the zone (zl) I want to cover in wire. I know the pitch (p) I want the helix to wrap to.

How do these three parameters (c, zl, p) relate to give me my wire length (wl)?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The parametric equation of the helix can be written $$x=r\cos(t),y=r\sin(t),z=ht.$$

Using the differential arc length we obtain
$$S(t)=\int_0^t\sqrt{\dot x^2+\dot y^2+\dot z^2}\,dt=\int_0^t\sqrt{r^2+h^2}\,dt=\sqrt{r^2+h^2}\,t.$$

Remains to make the connection to your own descriptive parameters.